# How to make Kivy Window fit the screen?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to repositon the window since

```
Window.size=(window_width,window_height)
```

takes the standard position of any Kivy app und so my program does not fit on the screen. I've tried

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'top',  0)
```

at the beginning of my source, at the

```
__main__
```

and in the build method of the app. Nothing seems to work. The same goes for setting the size with the config and possibly everything else with the Config

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it either your way and somehow find out system screen size

```
from kivy.config import Config
# topleft, size (50, 50)
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'top',  0)
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (50, 50)  # input system window size
```

OR, you can set the Window to be fullscreen directly:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 1)

from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
runTouchApp(Button())
```

Comment: Yes thank you for the comment but the first thing does nothing when I add it to my file and second I dont want fullscreen I have a custom resolution for my Program, but since the resolution ist set with the Window.size it is set after the initialization and the programm is not fully visible on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the Problem by reading in the API of the Kivy Configuration Object. You need to set it at the very start or other imports can override the config!

> In order to avoid situations where the config settings do not work or are not applied before window creation (like setting an initial window size), Config.set should be used before importing any other Kivy modules. Ideally, this means setting them right at the start of your main.py script.